# How to replace a word in a string by another word without using built-in replace function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to recreate the "replace" function in python on my own, but I'm having a hard time.

My function takes three inputs, the occurrence of the first string in the third string is replaced by the second string.

Example:

```
replace("with", "by" , "Don't play without your friends")
Result: ("Don't play byout your friends")
```

I tried this so far, but it isn't working, I think I overcomplicated it.

```
def replace(s, s1, s2):
    finall = list()
    l1 = s2.split()
    length_replace = len(s1)+1
    newlist = list()
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        if (s in l1[i]):
            newlist = list(l1[i])
            s = newlist[length_replace:]
            s = ''.join(s)
            final = s1 + s
            l1[i-1:i+1]= [final]
    return l1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I said I'm trying to create the replace() function on my own.. Did you even read my question?

Comment: What's not working? Be more specific and if you have a trace error please post it

Comment: Also please do not tag both python3 and python2. I will remove Python2 as your code pertains to 3

Comment: I do not quite understand why are you using lists and not just slicing over the strings...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it assuming that there is at most a single occurrence:

```
def replace(source, match, replacing):
    result = None
    for i in range(0, len(source) - len(match)):
        if source[i:i+len(match)] == match:
            result = source[:i] + replacing + source[i+len(match):]
            break
    if not result:
        result = source
    return result


replace("Don't play without your friends", "with", "by")
# "Don't play byout your friends"
```

For more than a single occurrence you could either write this recursively with the reminder of the `source` or include a few temp variables to store the aggregate result from previous iterations, e.g.:

```
def replace(source, match, replacing):
    result = ''
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(source) - len(match):
        if source[i:i+len(match)] == match:
            result += source[j:i] + replacing
            i += len(match)
            j = i
        else:
            i += 1
    result += source[j:]
    return result


replace('To be or not to be, this is the question!', 'be', 'code')
# 'To code or not to code, this is the question!'

replace('To be or not to be, this is the question!', 'is', 'at')
# 'To be or not to be, that at the question!'
```

And just to see that this behaves like the `str.replace()` function:

```
source = 'To be or not to be, this is the question!'
match = 'is'
replacing = 'at'
replace(source, match, replacing) == source.replace(match, replacing)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
def replace(s, s1, s2):
    tokens = s2.split()
    if s in tokens:
       tokens[tokens.index(s)] = s1
    return ' '.join(tokens)
```

Here is the test output:

```
>>> def replace(s, s1, s2):
...     tokens = s2.split()
...     if s in tokens:
...        tokens[tokens.index(s)] = s1
...     return ' '.join(tokens)
... 
>>> replace("with", "by" , "Don't play without your friends")
"Don't play without your friends"
>>>
```

Comment: this would only replace whitespace-separated strings... and it would not work with the test provided by OP

Comment: It was implemented the way he wanted it.

Comment: Have you tried running `replace("with", "by" , "Don't play without your friends")`? Do you get `"Don't play byout your friends"`?

Comment: I tested it and it worked as expected. I will update my post with my test.

Comment: The only drawback of that simple implementation is that it will only replace the first occurrence of the ```s``` with ```s1``` in ```s2```, but that is easily fixed with a for loop.

Comment: ... look more closely the word "without" should become "byout" and it does not with your code...

Comment: I guess that was exactly what he wanted to avoid: replacing substrings. But maybe I got it wrong.

Comment: From what OP writes, it looks like he wants to recreate `str.replace()`, and that function works also for non whitespace-separated strings

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of creating the replace function:

```
replacy = ("with", "by" , "Don't play without your friends")
def replace_all (target,find,replace):
  return replace.join(target.split(find))
target = replacy[2]
find = replacy[0]
replace = replacy[1]
print(replace_all(target, find, replace))
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> def replace(s1, s2, text):
...     text = re.sub(s1, s2, text)
...     return text
...
>>> print(replace("with", "by" , "Don't play without your friends"))
Don't play byout your friends
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as using `replace` but with a different library. He wants recreate it himself.